# C++/CLI cross-project parameter names in Intellisense (VS2013)

Tags: c++-cli, intellisense

I'm working on a multi-project program in C++/CLI and parameter names for functions, constructors etc. are not showing up properly in the Intellisense window. When I start typing a function call within the project, all goes well, but as soon as I use said project in another project (still within the same solution), VS shows funky parameter names (e.g. `myobj.move(int A_0,int A_1)`) instead of the names I gave them in the code. I've tried using the `///<param>` thing, but that works only within the same project, not in other projects (again, in the same solution). I've enabled the `/doc` option in the project properties, but that didn't do it. Is there a way to feed the generated XML file (or .xdc I guess?) into Intellisense? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not abnormal, C++ doesn't require parameter names but .NET does.  So if you didn't write them in the *declaration* of the method then the compiler is forced to fall back to auto-generated names.  Like A_0, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you declare the function prototype in a header file without the argument names:

```
#file.h

ref class A
{
void move(int ,int );
}
```

You should just add the names you want:

```
file.h

ref class A
{
void move(int MyArgument1,int MyOtherArgument);
}
```